# Error reported (expression must have a constant value) while parameterizing sc_lv

Tags: c++, gcc, systemc

I am working on System C. In a class

First I have declared a integer:

```
int G_WIDTH;
```

Then I am using G_WIDTH in :

```
sc_in < sc_lv <G_WIDTH> > a;
```

When I am trying to simulate it. Following error is reported:

> Expression <*sc_in < sc_lv  > a;*> must have a constant
>   value.

When I use :

```
sc_in < sc_lv <8> > a;
```

It is working fine.

Can anyone help me out in solving this problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's because `G_WIDTH` isn't a constant. If you make `G_WIDTH` constant it should work:

```
const int G_WIDTH = 8;
```